# Eclipse installs my app twice on my android phone

Tags: android, eclipse

I am having issues with Eclipse. I'm new to Android development so I wouldn't be surprised if I messed something up along the way.

My app installs twice on my phone. When I click 'Run', Eclipse does the usual with installation, but when it is finished, the app shows up twice (ie. two separate icons) on my phone. Any ideas what the problem is?

Comment: I presume you have deleted the icons and repeated this problem?  To delete them, be sure to go the manage-applications and uninstall them -- make sure they are completely gone.

Comment: what if you type in adb uninstall your_package? can you uninstall both? And could you post the AndroidManifest.xml?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your manifest:

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.myapp.FirstActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Apptheme" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.myapp.SecondActivity"/>
</application>
```

make sure only your first activity has an intent-filter.

Comment: This did it. I had an intent filter on a menu activity and a splash screen activity.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall both programs from the emulator. If you change the name of the program and/or change some of the settings, then it can install as a different program. My guess is after you do the install, then run that you'll only have the one icon.

Answer (score 0):

Did you run two different versions of this code?

If so it will not save over the old icon but make a new one.

If this is the case trying deleting boths apps from the emulator and re-running it cleanly.

Comment: No, but @Niek told me what I did wrong. It was the same app, but the launcher icon was installed twice.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had two activities with the following `intent-filter`

```
<intent-filter>
   <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
</intent-filter>
```